# elm-ui center elements in wrapped row

Tags: elm, elm-ui

I'm using Elm with mdgriffiths/elm-ui, and I've really been enjoying it. Right now, I'm trying to create a centered, wrapped row of elements:

[image]

I can get it to this point:

[image]

using this code:

```
button : String -> String -> Element Msg
button label url =
    link
        [ height (px 150)
        , width (px 150)
        , Border.width 1
        , Background.color (rgb255 255 255 255)
        ]
        { url = url
        , label =
            Element.paragraph
                [ Font.center ]
                [ textEl [] label ]
        }


row : Element Msg
row =
    Element.wrappedRow
        [ Element.spacing 25
        , Element.centerX
        , Element.centerY
        , width (fill |> Element.maximum 600)
        , Font.center
        ]
        [ button "A" "/a"
        , button "B" "/b"
        , button "C" "/c"
        , button "D" "/d"
        ]
```

But when I try adding Element.centerX to my buttons like this

```
link
    [ Element.centerX
    , ...
    ]
```

I get this instead:

[image]

I've also tried `Font.center` without success, and I don't know what else I can try.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something I should be using, or if the whole thing needs re-arranging, or if I just need to use the built-in CSS stuff.

**Update:**

Link to an Ellie with the issues I'm seeing.

https://ellie-app.com/7NpM6SPfhLHa1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Github issue](https://github.com/mdgriffith/elm-ui/issues/57) is useful for this problem. I'm afraid you will have to use some CSS (unless I'm missing something). I've found this before with elm-ui; every now and then it can't quite do what you want and you need a bit of CSS.

This works for me (taken from the post by AlienKevin in the link above). You need to set "marginLeft" and "marginRight" to "auto".

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Element as E
import Element.Border
import Html.Attributes


box : String -> E.Element msg
box label =
    E.paragraph
        [ E.width <| E.px 200
        , Element.Border.width 1
        , E.htmlAttribute (Html.Attributes.style "marginLeft" "auto")
        , E.htmlAttribute (Html.Attributes.style "marginRight" "auto")
        ]
        [ E.text label ]


row : E.Element msg
row =
    E.wrappedRow []
        [ box "A"
        , box "B"
        , box "C"
        ]


main =
    E.layout [] row
```

(See [here](https://ellie-app.com/7NVdbx5FD4wa1) for an Ellie.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

1. Define the following elm-ui classes. I usually setup a UI.elm module for this

```
centerWrap : Attribute msg
centerWrap =
    Html.Attributes.class "centerWrap"
        |> htmlAttribute


dontCenterWrap : Attribute msg
dontCenterWrap =
    Html.Attributes.class "dontCenterWrap"
        |> htmlAttribute
```

2. Add the following to your css. Basically says center elements if has centerWrap class but not dontCenterWrap class.

```
:not(.dontCenterWrap).centerWrap>div.wrp {
    justify-content: center !important;
}
```

3. Apply the attribute

```
    wrappedRow [ width fill, UI.centerWrap, spaceEvenly ] [...]
```

4. Assuming you created a custom element that centerWraps and wanted to disable that you could use UI.dontCenterWrap

```
centerWrappedRow attr children =
    wrappedRow (UI.centerWrap :: attr) children

-- somewhere else
...
    centerWrappedRow [UI.dontCenterWrap] [..]
...
```